# Qt: What does the "Main Event Loop" of a QApplication do?

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling

From [doc.qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec).

```
int QApplication::exec()

Enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called
```

What happens between this call and the `exit()` call? What is the order that paintEvents, cursorMoveEvents, cursorOverObjectEvents, signals, slots, etc are polled for? Are they polled at all, and if not then how does it work?

Comment: If you want to track the events, their order and parameters you can sub class `QApplication` and override its `QApplication::notify()` function. There you can debug output all the information and call parent class' `QApplication::notify()` at the end to make it work properly.

Comment: This [document](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html) complements the document you read from.

Comment: @vahancho Could you explain what you mean by "call parent class' QApplication::notify() at the end to make it work properly". Do you mean I should call the parent notify() function at the end of the subclasses  notify() funtion?

Comment: @Blue7, correct. I.e. `bool MyApp::notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *e) { [...] return QApplication::notify(receiver, e);}`, where `MyApp` is a subclass of `QApplication`.